# How do i create dropdown list and textboxes same id names with the help of index

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

[image: 1]

i created this page.. here in dropdown list i given for all id's name as same..so if i need to select 1st row dropdown then i need to fetch details in next dropdown in same row..but if i selected in last row dropdown its fetching details in 1st row..but i need fetch same row..  can anyone help me.

```
<tr>
<%-- <td class="td1">${row.index+1}</td> --%>
<td class="td1"><input readonly class="sno"  name="sno" id="sno" value="1" size="1"></td>
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserType[]" disabled id="UserType[]" onchange="showUserRole(this.value);" style="width: 130px;">
       <option value="CD5306">Doctor</option>   

        </select>&nbsp;     
</td> 

 <td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserRole[]" id="UserRole[]" onchange="fetchUsers(this.value);" style="width: 150px;">
         <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
         <c:forEach var="x" items="${UserRole1}">
             <option ${UserRole eq x.ID ? 'selected':''} value="${ x.ID }">${x.VALUE }</option>   
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;</td>
        
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <select  name="Name[]" id="Name[]" onchange="fetchCfms(this.value);" style="width: 150px;" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
        <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
        <c:forEach var="x" items="${Name}">
                    
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;
        </td>       
    
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" readonly name="cfmsid[]" id="cfmsid[]" value="${cfmsid }" size="10">&nbsp;
        </td>   
 <td class="td1">
  &nbsp;<img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/add1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="addField(this)" title="Click here to addmore">&nbsp;
        <img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/remove1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="removeManpower(this)" title="Click here to remove">&nbsp;
        </td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>
<%-- <td class="td1">${row.index+1}</td> --%>
<td class="td1"><input readonly class="sno"  name="sno" id="sno" value="2" size="1"></td>
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserType[]" id="UserType[]" disabled onchange="showUserRole(this.value);" style="width: 130px;">
       <option value="CD5307">Staff Nurse</option>
        </select>&nbsp;     
</td> 

 <td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserRole[]" id="UserRole[]" onchange="fetchUsers(this.value);" style="width: 150px;">
         <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
         <c:forEach var="x" items="${UserRole2}">
                 <option ${UserRole eq x.ID ? 'selected':''} value="${ x.ID }">${x.VALUE }</option>     
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;</td>
        
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <select  name="Name[]" id="Name[]" onchange="fetchCfms(this.value);" style="width: 150px;" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
        <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
        <c:forEach var="x" items="${Name}">
                    
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;
        </td>       
    
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" readonly name="cfmsid[]" id="cfmsid" value="${cfmsid }" size="10">&nbsp;
        </td>   
 <td class="td1">
  &nbsp;<img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/add1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="addField(this)" title="Click here to addmore">&nbsp;
        <img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/remove1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="removeManpower(this)" title="Click here to remove">&nbsp;
        </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
<td class="td1"><input readonly class="sno"  name="sno" id="sno" value="3" size="1"></td>
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserType[]" id="UserType[]" disabled onchange="showUserRole(this.value);" style="width: 130px;">
       <option value="CD5308">Class IV</option>
        </select>&nbsp;     
</td> 

 <td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserRole[]" id="UserRole[]" onchange="fetchUsers(this.value);" style="width: 150px;">
         <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
         <c:forEach var="x" items="${UserRole3}">
                 <option ${UserRole eq x.ID ? 'selected':''} value="${ x.ID }">${x.VALUE }</option>     
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;</td>
        
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <select  name="Name[]" id="Name[]" onchange="fetchCfms(this.value);" style="width: 150px;" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
        <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
        <c:forEach var="x" items="${Name}">
                    
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;
        </td>       
    
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" readonly name="cfmsid" id="cfmsid" value="${cfmsid }" size="10">&nbsp;
        </td>   
 <td class="td1">
  &nbsp;<img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/add1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="addField(this)" title="Click here to addmore">&nbsp;
        <img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/remove1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="removeManpower(this)" title="Click here to remove">&nbsp;
        </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
<%-- <td class="td1">${row.index+1}</td> --%>
<td class="td1"><input  class="sno" readonly name="sno" id="sno" value="4" size="1"></td>
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserType[]" id="UserType[]" disabled onchange="showUserRole(this.value);" style="width: 130px;">
       <option value="CD5309">Lab Technician</option>
        </select>&nbsp;     
</td> 

 <td class="td1">&nbsp;
       <select name="UserRole[]" id="UserRole[]" onchange="fetchUsers(this.value);" style="width: 150px;">
         <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
         <c:forEach var="x" items="${UserRole4}">
                 <option ${UserRole eq x.ID ? 'selected':''} value="${ x.ID }">${x.VALUE }</option>     
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;</td>
        
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <select  name="Name[]" id="Name[]" onchange="fetchCfms(this.value);" style="width: 150px;" onblur="getIndexValue(this)">
        <option value="-1">------Select------</option>
        <c:forEach var="x" items="${Name}">
                    
        </c:forEach>
        </select>&nbsp;
        </td>       
    
<td class="td1">&nbsp;
        <input type="text" readonly name="cfmsid" id="cfmsid" value="${cfmsid }" size="10">&nbsp;
        </td>   
 <td class="td1">
  &nbsp;<img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/add1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="addField(this)" title="Click here to addmore">&nbsp;
        <img src="/ASRI/ASRI-images/remove1.png" height="30" width="30" onclick="removeManpower(this)" title="Click here to remove">&nbsp;
        </td>
  </tr>
```

anyone have any idea???

Comment: Your ids are invalid  - you're not allowed square brackets in them and they need to be unique.  Also you have to at least try to solve this yourself and then if you get stuck, come back with a specific issue with the code you have tried

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique. I suspect that the problem you are having is because of duplicate IDs - there are other, more robust, methods to select DOM elements based upon events within Javascript so you should use the event to identify the element and it's parent/siblings rather than simply rely upon ID